# Entity Framework persisting child collection sort order

Tags: entity-framework-4, ctp4

In NHibernate I can map a collection as a List to persist the order of the collection to the database.

I'm using EF Code First (CTP4). How can I persist the sort order of a child collection (IList) without exposing the relationship in my domain model?

Comment: In short - you can't. You have to expose the relationship in your model.

Comment: i have the same problem. im looking for en alternative to 'index column' in nHibernate:  <list name="GroupList" table="tblGroup" cascade="all" inverse="true">
            <key column ="ParentId" />
            <index column="OrderPosition" type="Int32" />
            <one-to-many class ="Group" />
</list>