# Entity Framework (.NET Full Framework) Ordering Includes

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am trying to get something like the following to work:

```
_dbmsParentSections = FactoryTools.Factory.PdfSections
                        .Include(x => x.Children.OrderBy(y => y.Order).ToList())
                        .Include(x => x.Hint).Include(x => x.Fields)
                        .Where(x => x.FormId == FormId && x.Parent == null)
                        .OrderBy(o => o.Order)
                        .ToList();
```

The part that causes the exception is:

```
.Include(x => x.Children.OrderBy(y => y.Order).ToList())
```

**EDIT:**

Upon further observation,

```
_dbmsParentSections.ForEach(x => x.Children = x.Children.OrderBy(y => y.Order).ToList());
```

did the job for me (after the initial `Factory` call and without the `Children.OrderBy`).

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer you found worked for me aswell

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/15171

Comment: .Include(x => x.Children.OrderBy(y => y.Order))
Works for me!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It seems you cannot sort the children collection in your query.
Either sort after the query or load the children in a second query.

Similar question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938956/entity-framework-loading-child-collection-with-sort-order)

Comment: I've given you the credit because you were the first to answer and all three answers pretty much say the same thing

Comment: Is this still true with EF version 6.0 ?

Answer (score 71):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) documentation, starting with EF Core 5.0, you can sort by a property of your Included Entity:

```
 await context.Parents
    .OrderBy(parent => parent.Order)
    .Include(parent => parent.Children.OrderBy(child => child.Order))
    .ToListAsync();
```

The above example sorts Parent entities by their Order, as well as their Children entities by the Children entities' Order property.

Comment: Works great for me!

Answer (score 13):

The extension method `Include`is a mere wrapper around [`DbQuery.Include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbquery.include%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). Internally it does not *execute* the expressions but only *parses* them, i.e. it takes their member expressions and converts them to a path as string. The path is used as input for `DbQuery.Include`.

It has been requested before to enhance the functionality of `Include`, e.g. to allow partly loaded collections by including a `Where` clause. Ordering could be another change request. But as you see, because of the internal working of `Include` the whole mechanism will have to be re-engineered to implement such enhancements. I don't see it on the current [road map](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Roadmap) so it may take a while...

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the use case you might not need to load in separate query or sort afterwards.

In my case I needed them ordered for when looping in the view so I just ordered there

```
@foreach (var subObject in Object.SubObjects.OrderBy(x=>x.Order))
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this  code por order the include, using a select and a function to order the collection.
Is not the best but work fine if subcollection is small

```
   // GET: api/Tareas
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Tarea> GetTareas()
    {
        var result = _context.Tareas
            .Include(p => p.SubTareas)
            .Select(p => SortInclude(p));
        return result;
    }

    private Tarea SortInclude(Tarea p)
    {
        p.SubTareas = (p.SubTareas as HashSet<SubTarea>)?
            .OrderBy(s => s.Position)
            .ToHashSet<SubTarea>();
        return p;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will never gona work. EF include is try to understand and translate everything to SQL, but you want to much from this. Load all entities without sorting and .ToList()-ing, and write an extension method for IEnumerable to get an ordered result.

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you're using a bunch of includes, it's because you need to access child properties in a view.  What I do is order the child collection when I need to access it in a view.

For example, I might build some Include statements for a master/detail form.  There's no sense ordering this at the initial EF query.  Instead, why not order these child records at the view level when you're actually accessing them?

I might have a survey with multiple survey questions.  If I want to present the questions in a particular order at do it at the partial view level when I'm passing the model child collection to the partial view.

```
@Html.Partial("_ResponsesPartial",Model.SurveyResponses.OrderBy(x => 
x.QuestionId))
```

Answer (score -4):

You should not convert an `IQueryable` type to `IEnumerable` and call `Include` because `Include` is not supported by `IEnumerable` type.

In short, never call Include after `ToList`

```
IQueryable = server side call (SQL)
IEnumerable = client side (loaded in memory)
```

Comment: Your point is true, but it has nothing to do with the question that is asked. I'm trying to do the `Include` before the `ToList`