# Linq querying my include-statement

Tags: c#, linq

I want to retrieve a DB set with as few obsolete-data as possible, so I wrote the following include-statement

```
using (var context = this.Container.Resolve<IDbContextScope>()
{
    var databaseRequirements = context.Requirements
      .Include(x => x.RequirementVersions.MaxBy(y => y.Version))
      .Include(x => x.RequirementVersions.Select(y => y.RequirementDetails));
}
```

so later I can use my foreach;

```
foreach (MyRequirement requirement in databaseRequirements)
{
    var databaseRequirementDetails = requirement.RequirementVersion.FirstOrDefault()?.RequirementDetails;
    // Some more code that uses the var...
}
```

The database that is used here has 3 tables, `Requirements`, `RequirementVersions`, `RequirementDetails`. 1 `Requirement` has many `RequirementVersions` and 1 `RequirementDetails` has many `RequirementVersions`.

I initially ran with the `MaxBy()` from the `.Include()`-statement in place of the `.FirstOrDefault()`, but that'll retrieve all the old versions of a requirement, which I don't need in this particular method (and depending on the amount of requirements/requirementversions may slow the whole method down tremendously).

**On to the actual problem;** When I run this, I get

> The include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

I couldn't find anything on how to write this statement in a way it's accepted and does what I intend to do. It's an optimization-effort, so as long as it runs quicker than the alternative I'll settle.

**Edit:** It is not a duplicate of [the linked article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980665/ef-lambda-the-include-path-expression-must-refer-to-a-navigation-property) because the linked article's accepted answer returns a single object, whereas I need a list of objects who's lists contain a single object.

Comment: Linq To SQL and Entity Framework does not support filtered includes.

Comment: The number of open/closed parenthesis do no match in the include statement.  Until you fix that error the code will not compile properly.

Comment: @jdweng my bad, I copied the piece of code while I was editing it. I've updated the mainpost to match open/close. Original problem was not a compile error though, but a runtime error.

Comment: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/47