# Nested Include With Sort

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a data structure that looks something like this:

```
main(main_id, name)
container(container_id), order, name)
item(item_id, name)
item_order(item_order_id, order, item_id)
```

- There is a many to one relationship between container and main
- There is a many to one relationship between item_order and container
- There is a one to one relationship between item_order and item (the same item can show up in multiple containers, which is why the ordering information is stored in a separate table rather than the same one like container)

What I want to do for a specific main is select all the containers in ascending order, along with all the items (through their order objects) in ascending order.

I have tried [The Example I Found Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938956/entity-framework-loading-child-collection-with-sort-order), and it works great for sorting the containers, what I cannot figure out is how to expand this to sorting the items within the containers.

Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. EF materializes nested collections in the order they happen to come from the database. We can't do a thing like `context.containers.Include(c => c.Items.OrderBy(...))`.

It's been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15378136/861716) whether the `Include` method could have an `OrderBy`, but to this day it hasn't. It's occasionally a pain, but I don't expect this to change any time soon. There are some alternatives:

- Order the items when necessary (e.g. for display)
- Project the containers and items to a view model in which the items are sorted.
- Create a (unmapped) property like SortedItems in `container`. But note that this property can only be addressed when the objects have been materialized, a query like `context.containers.Select(c => c.SortedItems)` would throw an error.