# Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid when aggregate and adding specific condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

am using specification pattern (1) with EF Core 3.1.7.
I generate an IQueryable object then I want to apply the specification for my use cases.

IQueryable builder method (Base specification method AddInclude) :

```
query = specification.Includes.Aggregate(query,
  (current, include) => current.Include(include));
```

When I use Include method, it works correctly.

But I need to add custom include conditions. For example:

```
private void IncludePrice()
{
   AddInclude(x => x.Prices.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationDate));
}
```

EF Core does not generate queries with this lambda expression. It throws:

Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid.

How can I solve this?

Comment: `AddInclude` sounds like it is for including child objects, not sorting the results. It should be `AddInclude(x => x.Prices);` You'll have do the sorting separately.

Comment: how can i do that ?

Comment: Unless you have a real need to sort the prices I would be leaving this to your UI. Nevertheless, that is a different question!

Comment: I really need to do that.Will you please help? :(

Comment: The problem with `Include` was obvious to me. Unfortunately I'm not as familiar with the sorting, Sorry

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15378136/10608418