# Sorting and selecting latest on Navigation Property in EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, navigation-properties

Consider the below code

```
private List<Orders> GetOrders(int id) 
{
  var result = Context.Orders.Where(x => x.OrderId == 15)
                    .Include(x => x.Products)
                    .Include(x => x.CustomerDetails)
                    .ToList();
  return result;
}
```

Products and CustomerDetails are Navigation properties on Orders Entity. I just want to get results with details about the most expensive product only.

So I tried below,

```
Context.Orders.Where(x => x.OrderId == 15)
                    .Include(x => x.Products.OrderByDescending(p => p.Price).Take(1))
                    .Include(x => x.CustomerDetails)
                    .ToList();
```

But this is resulting in an error,

*An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.*

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938956/entity-framework-loading-child-collection-with-sort-order) answer, it is not possible.  Perhaps the best answer to your specific problem is to order the products after loading.

Comment: or indeed the answer below it, where it shows how to do it !!  I must read past the first answer next time...